# Intersection point of multiple 3D lines

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangulation

I want to compute the intersection point $q$ of multiple lines in 3D space 
that minimizes the distance from $q$ to the lines. Lines are noisy and can be slightly skew. For this, I solve a linear system.

Lines are expressed as a point $p$ and a vector $v$:

$ l_i \equiv p_i + \lambda v_i $

In the case of two lines, I have that 
$ q = (p_1 + \lambda_1 v_1) = (p_2 + \lambda_2 v_2)$, for some $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$.
I can build this $Ax=b$ linear system to find $\lambda_i$:
$ 
\left[ \begin{matrix} v_1, ~ -v_2 \end{matrix} \right] 
\left[ \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \end{matrix} \right] = p_2 - p_1
$.

For $N$ lines, I can think about the next $Ax=b$ structure:

$
\left[ \begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & -v_{1x} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -v_{1y} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -v_{1z} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
& & & & \dots \\
1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0& \dots & -v_{Nx} \\
0 & 1 & 0  & 0 & 0& \dots & -v_{Ny}\\
0 & 0 & 1  & 0 & 0& \dots & -v_{Nz}\\
\end{matrix} \right] 
\left[ \begin{matrix}
q_x \\ q_y \\ q_z \\ \lambda_1 \\ \dots \\ \lambda_N
\end{matrix} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{matrix}
p_{1x} \\ p_{1y} \\ p_{1z} \\ \dots \\ p_{Nx} \\ p_{Ny} \\ p_{Nz}
\end{matrix} \right]
$.

The system finds both the intersection point $q$ and the $\lambda_i$ parameters. However they are not independent, so I have the feeling this system is more complex than it should be.

Is this system correct, or is there a better solution to this? Also, for $N$ lines, how can I check if the system gives me a reliable solution (e.g. to tell if all the lines are parallel)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to find a single point of intersection for many lines (in which case you find the point for 2 lines, you have found them for all), the intersection points for pairs of lines (but not all pairs will have them--line 1 intersecting lines 2, and line 2 intersecting line 3 does not imply that line 1 intersects line 3)?

Comment: I edited the question. I want to get a single point that minimizes its distance to all the noisy lines. If there was no noisy, this would be the intersection point of all the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Transform each line equation into the intersection of two planes. You can do that by taking two vectors normal to $v_i$ and impose that each plane pass through the point $p_i$.
Then for each couple of lines, you have a linear system of $4$ equations in $3$ unknowns, which - by the usual conditions on the ranks - will tell you if there are $0$,$1$, or infinite solutions.
If you want to check if $n$ lines are concurrent, you may construct the $2n$ x $3$ = $2n$ x $1$ system and examine if there are the conditions for it to admit a unique solution.